# Makefile basics

Tags: c, makefile

I am having trouble with the basics of makefile.

I use gcc to compile

What I need to do is make a makefile named labMakefile and the targets are

```
lab
labM.o
labG.o
clean
```

the files already in the folder that i'm working on consist of

```
labM.c
labM.o
labG.c
labG.o
```

I have been looking at makefile tutorials but I cant seem to find the proper way to create a makefile

What i have tried

```
labMakefile: labM.o labG.o
```

but it just says `labMakefile:: command not found`

Comment: I doubt it gives you that error message, because it's a different capitalisation.  Unless, of course...

Comment: i think `make -f labMakeFile lab`

Comment: Well, your makefile is called `labMakefile` (apparently), not `labMakeFile`, so there's one problem.  The second problem is that you're asking it to build the target `lab`, but your makefile doesn't have any target called `lab`.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. And yes you're right about the target `lab` but it was stated in the question so its confusing me :x

Comment: Ah, sorry I misread your question.  Ok, you'll need to edit your question to include your Makefile (please make it as short as you possibly can).

Comment: Does labMakefile need to be made beforehand? like `touch labMakefile` ? I'm very lost in this concept

Comment: `touch` just updates the last-modified info.  It doesn't affect anything for a makefile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A makefile is a script which is run by Make. It is just a text file written with a strict grammar which Make needs, like source code (although it is interpreted, not compiled). You can use any text editor you like to create it.

You are using C (judging by the suffixes on your filenames). So to create `labM.o` from `labM.c` you'd probably use a command like

```
gcc -c labM.c -o labM.o
```

(Not that the `-o labM.o` is really needed, it's the default behavior, I'm just trying to spell things out a little.) Likewise to build `labG.o` you'd use

```
gcc -c labG.c -o labG.o
```

and then (I guess) you'd link them together to build lab:

```
gcc labM.o labG.o -o lab
```

And sometimes you'd want to clear out the constructed files:

```
rm -f *.o lab
```

So to do all of this, you'd write a makefile called `Makefile`that looked like this (note that the leading spaces are TABs):

```
labM.o:
    gcc -c labM.c -o labM.o

labG.o:
    gcc -c labG.c -o labG.o

lab:
    gcc labM.o labG.o -o lab

.PHONY:clean
clean:
    rm -f *.o lab
```

Then you could `make lab` or `make clean` or `make labM.o labG.o`. If you really want to call this makefile `labMakefile`, you can do so, but then you'll have to do e.g. `make -f labMakefile lab`. **This makefile is crude but effective.** It could be greatly improved upon:

```
CC = gcc

lab: labM.o labG.o
    gcc $^ -o $@

lab%.o: lab%.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY:clean
clean:
    @echo cleaning things up, boss...
    @rm -f *.o lab
```

This will handle dependencies better: if you modify `labM.c` but not `labG.c`, and then `make`, Make will know that `labM.o` (and `lab`) must be rebuilt, but `labG.o` need not be.

This is a lot to take in, and further improvement is possible (dependency handling can be made *very* slick), but it's a good start.

Comment: I already have labM.o , why do I need to create it from labM.c?

And for 

`labM.o:
    gcc -c labM.c -o labM.o

labG.o:
    gcc -c labG.c -o labG.o

lab:
    gcc labM.o labG.o -o lab

.PHONY:clean
clean:
    rm -f *.o lab`

is that inside a labMakefile?

Comment: @JA3N, if you want to make `lab` *only once*, you don't need a makefile, just something like `gcc labM.o labG.o -o lab`. A makefile automates the process so that you can modify a source and then just `make`. And yes, all that's in labMakefile.

Comment: The pattern rule to build objects is built-in, you needn't include that.

Comment: @blueshift: I know, it was pedagogical.

Answer (score 2):

To run a makefile, you must invoke "make"

If your makefile has not a standard name (makefile or Makefile), you should specify it with the -f argument :

```
make -f labMakefile
```

Comment: If i type that in it says 
`make: labMakefile: No such file or directory`
`make: *** No rule to make target labMakefile. Stop.`

Comment: Who, you didn't tell me enough ! What is the name of your makefile ?  In which directory.  Do not forget to cd to the correct directory then invoke make with "make -f replaceThisStringWithTheNameOfYourMakefile"

Comment: The name of my makefile _should_ be labMakefile, I guess I didnt make it yet.. which is one of the problems i'm having with this. Sorry if I didn't mention that

Comment: I'm speaking of your **filename**, (not of your target which is also labMakefile).  What is the **filename** of your makefile ?  In which directory ?  Did you `cd path/to/dir` ?

Comment: This is all done in a folder called lab9. What do you mean labMakefile is a target? The question says to write a makefile named labMakefile :x